# What's the difference between 'A sequence of moments' and 'moment generating function' when it comes to uniquely determine distribution function

Tags: moment-generating-functions

I read from the MGB stats textbook which says something about "the problem of moments", as follows:
"In general, **a sequence of moments μ1,μ2..,μn,...** does not determine a unique distribution function；..., However,  if the moment generating function of a random variable did exist, then this **moment generating function did uniquely determine the corresponding distribution function** "

It is hard for me to see the difference between these two concepts（sequence of moments VS moment generating function). I've looked through several posts about this topic, and I know that someone did come up with a counterexample of a particular density family with the same sequence of moments:

[image]

I also read about the proof of the uniqueness of moment generating function.

But doesn't that sequence of moments define a moment generating function? As m(t) can be written as 
[image]

Can someone fill the gap for me? 
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the series for the moment generating function $m(t)$ might not converge anywhere except $t=0$.  The actual result is that if this series has positive radius of convergence, it uniquely determines the distribution.

In your example, the moments are $\mu_n = (4n+3)!/6$, and it's easy to see using the Ratio Test that the radius of convergence is $0$.

Comment: So you are saying "series of moments having positive radius of convergence" equals to "moment generating function exists". And when you say converge, you mean μn converges as n goes to infinity?

Comment: 1) Yes: it's not much of an existence if the moment generating function is defined only at $0$.
2) No, I mean the series $m(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\mu_n}{n!} t^n$ converges.